# Dynamic JavaScript Injection/Execution

Tags: javascript, dynamic, execution

A small little rundown of what I'm trying to do:

1) Dynamically determine if a browser is capable of playing HTML5 video (Working)

2) If not capable of playing HTML5 video, load Flash version of video, CSS, and page (Working)

3) If capable of playing HTML5 video, load HTML5 version of video, CSS, and page (Stuck)

All the code needed loads into the browser (IE10, IE11, and Chrome 36 have been tested).  The problem is with the execution of JavaScript that is added through the dynamic loading.  I'm using the Adobe Captivate CS6 publishing system for Flash and HTML5 output, and all my customized code works perfectly if the scripts are loaded normally, but not through this dynamic method.  To save a little bit of effort, I'm just going to post the code for the HTML5 version.

```
        function addExternalStyleSheet(href)
        {
            if(document.createStyleSheet)
            {
                document.createStyleSheet(href);
            }
            else
            {
                var newSheet = document.createElement('link');
                newSheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
                newSheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
                newSheet.setAttribute('href', href);
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newSheet);
            }
        }
        function addInternalStyleSheet(selector, attributes)
        {
            if(document.createStyleSheet)
            {
                var styleSheet = document.createStyleSheet('');
                styleSheet.cssText = selector + '{' + attibutes + '}';
            }
            else
            {
                var styleTag = document.createElement('style');
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                head.appendChild(styleTag);
                var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet;
                if(sheet.insertRule)
                    sheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + attributes + '}', 0);
                else
                    sheet.addRule(selector, attributes, 0);
            }
        }
        function addJavaScript(src)
        {
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            newScript.setAttribute('src', src);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
        }
        function generateEmbed()
        {
            if(fileType == 'html5')
            {
                addExternalStyleSheet('assets/playbar/playbarStyle.css');
                addExternalStyleSheet('assets/css/CPLibrary.css');
                addExternalStyleSheet('assets/css/CPQuiz.css');
                addExternalStyleSheet('assets/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css');
                addExternalStyleSheet('assets/css/dd.css');
                addInternalStyleSheet('.shadow', 'overflow: hidden;');
                addInternalStyleSheet('.cpMainContainer', 'background-color: transparent; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; position: absolute;');
                addInternalStyleSheet('.blocker', 'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;');
                addInternalStyleSheet('.loadingBackground', 'background-color: #777777; opacity: 0.5;');
                addInternalStyleSheet('.loadingString', 'color: #ffffff;');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/uncompressed.jquery.dd.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/uncompressed-jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPRuntimeDailog.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPLibrary.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPQuizLibrary.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPPlaybar.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPTOC.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/js/CPWidgetManager.js');
                addJavaScript('assets/playbar/playbarScript.js');
                addJavaScript('Project.js');
                document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '\n       <div class="cpMainContainer" id="cpDocument" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">\n            <div class="shadow" id="project_container" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">\n              <div id="project" class="cp-movie" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px">\n                  <div id="project_main" class="cp-timeline cp-main">\n                       <div id="div_Slide" onclick="handleClick(event)" style="top: 0px; width: 1280px; height: 720px; position: absolute; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);"><\/div>\n                  <\/div>\n                   <div id="autoplayDiv" style="display: block; text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">\n                       <img id="autoplayImage" src="" style="position: absolute; display: block; vertical-align: middle;" \/>\n                        <div id="playImage" tabindex="0" role="buton" aria-label="play" class="autoPlayButton" onkeydown="CPPlayButtonHandle(event)" onClick="cp.movie.play()" style="position: absolute; display: block; vertical-align: middle;"><\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n               <\/div>\n               <div id="playbar" style="left: 0px; float: left; position: absolute;"><\/div>\n             <div id="toc" style="left: 0px; float: left; position: absolute;"><\/div>\n             <div id="cc" style="left: 0px; float: left; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">\n                 <div id="ccText" style="left: 0px; float: left; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">\n                      <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-top: 2px;"><\/p>\n                    <\/div>\n                   <div id="ccClose" style="background-image: url(.\/assets\/Playbar_icons\/ccClose.png); right: 0px; float: right; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 13px; height: 11px;" onclick="showHideCC()"><\/div>\n              <\/div>\n               <div id="passwordDiv" style="display: block; text-align: center; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><\/div>\n             <div id="expDiv" style="display: block; text-align: center; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><\/div>\n          <\/div>\n       <\/div>\n       <div id="blockUserInteraction" class="blocker" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">\n            <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" id="loading" class="loadingBackground">\n             <tr style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">\n                   <td style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">\n                       <image id="preloaderImage"><\/image>\n                      <div id="loadingString" class="loadingString">Loading...<\/div>\n                   <\/td>\n                <\/tr>\n            <\/table>\n     <\/div>\n';
                function DoCPInit()
                {
                    CPPreInit();
                    cp.QuizLibraryInit();
                    CPPostInit();
                }
                document.oncomplete = DoCPInit();
            }
        }
```

I included all the functions for inserting files (internal and external CSS and JavaScript), in case the problem is there, though it took me several hours just to get the internal CSS function to work without disabling the JavaScript function. :S

When using the browser debugger in IE, it errors with the execution (as a part of the DoCPInit function) of the CPPreInit function, which is located in CPLibrary.js, the fifth script dynamically loaded.  The debugger states that the function is undefined.

Honestly, I'd prefer to use PHP to get this all done, but my hands are tied, so JavaScript has to get the job done, and I know it can, I'm just screwing it up. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion that the *complete* event is not firing when you expect, primarily because you're loading in these scripts dynamically, so independently to the resources after which *complete* fires.

It seems to me you actually need to listen for the [***load* event**](http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/) for each resource, count them and only when those are complete invoke `DoCPInit`

```
function resourceLoaded() {
    var ev = new Event('resourceLoaded', {bubbles: true});
    this.removeEventListener('load', resourceLoaded); // cleanup
    this.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

function loadResource(parent, tag, args) {
    var node = document.createElement(tag), arg;
    // add listeners on this line if needed
    node.addEventListener('load', resourceLoaded);
    for (arg in args) node.setAttribute(arg, args[arg]);
    parent.appendChild(node);
    return node;
}

function addJavaScript(src) {
    loadResource(
        document.head,
        {
            'type': 'text/javascript',
            'src': src
        }
    );
}

var waitfor = 1; // one script

document.addEventListener('resourceLoaded', function () {
    if (--waitfor > 0) return;
    // invoke whatever
    DoCPInit();
});
```

---

Partially tested it in *Chrome*, you may need to check compatibility over browsers

Comment: I had to edit your addJavaScript function to call the loadResource as:

 loadResource(
  document.head, 'script',
  {
   'type': 'text/javascript',
   'src': src
  }
 );

In either case, it now errors at the line "var ev = new Event('resourceLoaded', {bubbles: true});" as "Object doesn't support this action". :S

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: use a script from http://microjs.com/#loader to load the scripts and execute something after a load.  LABJs is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I took my cue from Paul S, but his code wasn't working.  Adding alerts to the first line in the dynamically loaded scripts showed that the DoCPInit function was called before the scripts were loaded, which is where the error came from.  To correct this, I moved the jQuery call to a standard SCRIPT tag and called the rest using $.AJAX() with async set to false.  To simplify the matter, I set it using an array, rather than 10 individual calls.

```js
var addJavaScript = [
  'assets/js/uncompressed.jquery.dd.js',
  'assets/js/uncompressed-jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.js',
  'assets/js/CPRuntimeDailog.js',
  'assets/js/CPLibrary.js',
  'assets/js/CPQuizLibrary.js',
  'assets/js/CPPlaybar.js',
  'assets/js/CPTOC.js',
  'assets/js/CPWidgetManager.js',
  'assets/playbar/playbarScript.js',
  'Project.js',
];
jQuery.each(addJavaScript, function (i, val) {
  jQuery.ajax({ async: false, dataType: 'script', url: val });
});
```